# Como activar diferentes sliders en una pagina al hacer click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo 3 banners con fotos de 3 lugares diferentes. Necesito que al hacer clic en una figura se active, en un recuadro, el banner del lugar 1, luego al hacer clic en otra figura se active, en el mismo recuadro, el banner del lugar 2 y así sucesivamente. Alguien me puede ayudar. Lo he intentado con javascript, pero no me sale.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner lo que has intentado y el html? Nos ayudaría mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te paso un jsfiddle que acabo de hacer muy sencillo para aclararte las ideas.

https://jsfiddle.net/57vtqvk4/12/

Los p dentro de los div del slider cambialos por las imagenes que quieres.

El código javascript funciona de la siguiente manera, tengo una variable actual inicializada a 1 que me dice que slider se esta mostrando actualmente, dicha variable la incremente en 1 cada vez que pulso el boton (o la figura en tu caso), tengo un data-total para poner cuantos sliders hay en total y así saber cuando he llegado al final, si el siguiente es mayor que el total, reinicio todo a 1.

Creo que quedará mas claro en el jsfiddle que te he pasado, si tienes dudas preguntame.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. Estoy tratando de adaptarla a mi caso, los <p> los estoy cambiando por los diferentes banners y creo que va a funcionar muy bien.

Comment: Te lo agradezco muchísimo, sobre todo por la simplicidad del código. Como yo soy muy novata en la programación, estoy estudiándolo :)

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos :)